# Unable to compile jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am unable to compile a jsp and get the following error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /jsp/org_1/Alpha.jsp
Duplicate local variable applicationURL
5: <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
6: <%@ page import="org.apache.log4j.Logger" %>
7: <%
8:      String applicationURL = (String) session.getAttribute("appURL");
9:      String cntxtName = "";
10:         
11:         if(null != applicationURL)


An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /jsp/org_1/Alpha.jsp
Duplicate local variable cntxtName
6: <%@ page import="org.apache.log4j.Logger" %>
7: <%
8:      String applicationURL = (String) session.getAttribute("appURL");
9:      String cntxtName = "";
10:         
11:         if(null != applicationURL)
12:         {


 Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:415)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:308)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:316)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:557)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:481)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
at org.apache.jsp.jsp.org_005f1.Beta_jsp._jspService(Beta_jsp.java:135)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1063)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1063)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.tcs.ddf.servlets.gamma.checkBrowser(gamma.java:180)
at com.tcs.ddf.servlets.gamma.doFilter(gamma.java:40)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My jsp looks like this :

```
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
 <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
 <%@ page import="org.apache.log4j.Logger" %>
  <%
    String applicationURL = (String) session.getAttribute("appURL");
    String cntxtName = "";

    if(null != applicationURL)
    {
        cntxtName = applicationURL+"abc/";
    }
    else
    {
        cntxtName = "/abc/";
    }

    session.setAttribute("cntxtName",cntxtName);
     %>
  <head>
```

I have checked that both the string variables applicationURL and cntxtName are not used anywhere else. So why do I get the Duplicate local variable error. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: There might be chance that you have used it previously, but later removed, just restart the server to recompile the JSP again

Comment: Are you using tiles or similar? Why not to post a full stacktrace?

Comment: @ Aniket: I am still getting the same error, even after server restart.

Comment: @ Roman C, @ Prabhaker : I have edited the question, now u can see the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Duplicate local variable` exception generally occurs when other included JSPs files already declares the same local variable in the current jsp file.
for more info visit : http://www.appperfect.com/support/java-coding-rules/jsp.html#rule1.
So please make sure you do not have the same variable in the included jsp files.

Note:
It is always good to avoid scripting in JSPs(as @duffymo told you use JSTL instead)

Comment: thanks, But as can be seen from the code, i am not including any jsp in my Alpha.jsp page.

Comment: @ Prabhaker : I have edited the question . I have provided the full stacktrace now.

Comment: @sweetu514 The problem may be with including `Beta.jsp` file since stack trace showing the error `Beta_jsp.java:135`

Comment: @ Prabhaker: thanks, as I see, I use beta.jsp in a scriptlet tag ( on the current Alpha.jsp). Also Beta.jsp also contains the same two variables, applicationURL and cntxtName. Is that the cause of error ? and should I now not use the two String variable on my Alpha.jsp ?

Comment: @sweetu514 yes.,that is the problem.You should not declare the two variables already declared in the `Beta.jsp` file.So declare those variables with different names in `Alpha.jsp`.

Comment: @ Prabhaker: thanks prabhaker , that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using of Scriptlets `<% %>` in JSP. Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) it is simple and less line of code than scriptlets.

```
//get the value of appURL from session and set to variable applicationURL
<c:set var="applicationURL" value="${sessionScope.appURL}"></c:set>

//set the variable cntxtName default value to avoid else part
<c:set var="cntx" value="/abc/"></c:set>

//there is no if else so use 
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${not empty applicationURL}">     //empty also checks for null as well
    <c:set var="cntxtName" value="${applicationURL}${cntx}" scope="session"></c:set>
  </c:when> 
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:set var="cntxtName" value="${cntx}" scope="session"></c:set>
  </c:otherwise>  
</c:choose>
```

To run above code you need [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in class path. In JSP add

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

#### Related links

- [JSTL core](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html)
- [Tag set](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html)
- [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

Comment: @ Aniket: thanks, problem solved. will take care to learn JSTL / EL and use it instead of using scriptlet.